# zoomable PKCanvasView with underlaying background image

Tags: ios, swift, pencilkit

I like to make `PKCanvasView` to be scrollable and zoomable with underlay image.  It seems it is okay to make it scrollable and zoomable without underlaying background image.  But to make it with underlaying image I don’t know how to make it work.

Since `PKCanvasView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, I tried place custom content `UIView` within scroll view, then set a delegate to specify that view for zooming.  But `PKCanvasView`’s drawing image and content view will not synchronize their positions when zooming, it’s okay with scrolling.

```
+ UIView (root view)
    + PKCanvasView
        + Custom UIView (underlaying image drawing)
```

Then I tried `PKCanvasView` as just a content view within another `UIScrollView`, treat `PKCanvasView` as non-scrollable view.  Then I synchronize the positions between `PKCanvasView`’s drawing and container drawing image.  However, I am not sure whether, `PKCanvasView` may not be designed for being under another `UIScrollView`, behavior of positioning ruler by finger isn’t stable, kept jumping place to place by dragging.

```
+ UIView (root view)
    + UIScrollView
        + Custom UIView (underlaying image drawing)
            + PKCanvasView
```

As far as I know, most of `PKCanvasView` sample code work well without zooming with underlaying image.  But once I set to `maximumZoomScale` to 2 or more.  Then it no longer synchronize drawings and underlaying background image.

Thanks

Comment: I kept googling again, and I found a clue for this problem. Since, I cannot read Chinese, but I can read the code piece. https://stackoom.com/question/3pNGe/如何将UIImage转换或加载到PKDrawing中 I was experimenting on this for a while, and I post the project to GitHub. https://github.com/codelynx/PKCanvasViewTester

Answer (score 6):

Set up your `PKCanvasView` in `Main.storyboard` and link it to your `ViewController` (`@IBOutlet weak var canvasView: PKCanvasView!`) and adjust the following property (in your `Main.storyboard` or `viewDidLoad()` for the `ViewController`):

```
canvasView.isOpaque = false
```

Create also a custom `UIView view` in your `viewDidLoad()` and add it to your `PKCanvasView`:

```
canvasView.insertSubview(view, at: 0)
```

It's important that you insert it at 0, so it will be behind your drawings.

Create a new function `didZoom(to scale: CGFloat)` in an Extension of `UIView` or if you created a Subclass, add it there. There you can adjust your view to the new scale.

In your `ViewController` add a function like `updateContentSizeForDrawing()`:

```
func updateContentSizeForDrawing() {
        view.frame.size = canvasView.contentSize
        view.didZoom(to: canvasView.zoomScale)
}
```

I recommend to call this function at the end of your `viewWillAppear()`. To observe when the user zooms, add the delegate function to your `ViewController`:

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateContentSizeForDrawing()
}
```