# Scrollable PKCanvasView with SwiftUI subview

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, pencilkit, pkcanvasview

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61696722/zoomable-pkcanvasview-with-underlaying-background-image) on stackoverflow with this [source code](https://github.com/codelynx/PKCanvasViewTester) as possible solution.

How can I use a SwiftUI view instead of a UIImageView as `underlayView`?

I tried to replace the `UIImageView` with a `UIView` and converted my SwiftUI view with a UIHostingController to a UIView but this UIView was then invisible in the PKCanvasView.

Comment: if the solution is a `UIView` use a `UIViewRepresentable` if it is a `UIViewController` use a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`